# using netbeans 7.2.1 doing a diff between local and remote

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I have a netbeans php project that is local on my PC. I have it setup to save on the remote server "on save". This all works well. I now have a second developer in the mix who is doing the same thing to the same server .
Is there a tool/plugin or even standalone tool that that can do a recusive diff  or project diff between my PC and the remote server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "Copy files from Source Folder to another location"-feature is not meant to be used for more than one developer. It's good to use that feature for a local preview, for example when copying the files from the source folder (on save) to the webroot on the same PC or a local test server. By no means should the same preview folder be used by different developers. You still could use an external tool to have a diff done, but be aware that any files in the test folder are overwritten by Netbeans and it's pretty hard to find out which file was edited last by which developer.

Use a versioning system if you need to work on the same code by more than one developer.

Comment: thanks for the response. We are using a local and git repository already. But i do not populate the devel server from git. Still kind of new to the git process. Currently we are work in different sections and when we save via netbeans it pushes the file to our devel server so we can test. Once tested we commit and then push. I would appreciate suggestions to this process to help keep the devel server in sync with our PCs

Comment: @randy If you already commit it to some repository, just use the version systems tools to make diff and import missing files. Netbeans will also copy any files changed during a checkout to the test server.